# Validate XSD Failed - The attribute is not declared

Tags: xml, xsd, biztalk, xsd-validation

I have the following xml which I have trimmed down, but all it does is for every sku it has, it groups them up by the first 6 digits to form a product, which appears at the end of the file with more elements, e.g. below are 3 skus and 1 product:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<enfinity xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.0/xcs/impex catalog.xsd http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt dt.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.0/xcs/impex" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt" major="6" minor="1" family="enfinity" branch="enterprise" build="build">
  <offer sku="423182110">
    <short-description xml:lang="de-DE">Budlea Linen Skirt</short-description>
    <custom-attributes>
      <custom-attribute name="sizeEU" dt:dt="string">42</custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
  </offer>
  <offer sku="423182111">
    <short-description xml:lang="de-DE">Budlea Linen Skirt</short-description>
    <custom-attributes>
      <custom-attribute name="sizeEU" dt:dt="string">44</custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
  </offer>
  <offer sku="423182112">
    <short-description xml:lang="de-DE">Budlea Linen Skirt</short-description>
    <custom-attributes>
      <custom-attribute name="sizeEU" dt:dt="string">46</custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
  </offer>
  <offer sku="423182">
    <short-description xml:lang="de-DE">Budlea Linen Skirt</short-description>
    <variations>
      <mastered-products>
        <mastered-product sku="423182110" domain="WhiteStuff-MasterRepository" default="1" productvariationposition="500"/>
        <mastered-product sku="423182111" domain="WhiteStuff-MasterRepository" default="0" productvariationposition="600"/>
        <mastered-product sku="423182112" domain="WhiteStuff-MasterRepository" default="0" productvariationposition="700"/>
      </mastered-products>
      <variation-attributes>
        <variation-attribute name="size">
          <presentation-option>default</presentation-option>
          <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute name="displayName" dt:dt="string" xml:lang="en-US">Size</custom-attribute>
          </custom-attributes>
        </variation-attribute>
        <variation-attribute name="colour">
          <presentation-option>colorCode</presentation-option>
          <presentation-product-attribute-name>rgbColour</presentation-product-attribute-name>
          <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute name="displayName" dt:dt="string" xml:lang="en-US">Colour</custom-attribute>
          </custom-attributes>
        </variation-attribute>
      </variation-attributes>
    </variations>
    <custom-attributes>
      <custom-attribute name="sizeBridge" dt:dt="string">WW STD</custom-attribute>
      <custom-attribute name="washCareProfile" dt:dt="string">Machine Washable</custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
  </offer>
</enfinity>
```

I used [Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgqO9.png) to generate the xsd, which produced 2 files, first one is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:attribute name="dt" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

Second one is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.0/xcs/impex" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt" />
    <xs:element name="enfinity">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="offer">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="short-description">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="required" />
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="variations">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="mastered-products">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="mastered-product">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                            <xs:attribute name="sku" type="xs:unsignedInt" use="required" />
                                                            <xs:attribute name="domain" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                                            <xs:attribute name="default" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                                                            <xs:attribute name="productvariationposition" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
                                                        </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="variation-attributes">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="variation-attribute">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                                <xs:element name="presentation-option" type="xs:string" />
                                                                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="presentation-product-attribute-name" type="xs:string" />
                                                                <xs:element name="custom-attributes">
                                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                                        <xs:sequence>
                                                                            <xs:element name="custom-attribute">
                                                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                                                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                                                                            <xs:attribute ref="dt:dt" use="required" />
                                                                                            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="required" />
                                                                                        </xs:extension>
                                                                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                            </xs:element>
                                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                                </xs:element>
                                                            </xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                                        </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="custom-attributes">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="custom-attribute">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                                        <xs:attribute ref="dt:dt" use="required" />
                                                    </xs:extension>
                                                </xs:simpleContent>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="sku" type="xs:unsignedInt" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="major" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="minor" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="family" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="branch" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="build" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

First file is fine, although it's not got a lot of information in so not quite sure what it's for. Nonetheless when I save the 2nd file and tried to open it in Visual Studio, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB7Xx.png):

After clicking ok, I then tried to validate the schema, but only to receive [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMfDj.png) also. I did notice that the xml file references a schema called catalog.xsd but isn't used, so assuming it's not required, as well as another schema called dt.xsd which is used (dt:dt), which I have obtained from the client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    targetNamespace="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:attribute name="dt">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="int" />
                <xsd:enumeration value="double" />
                <xsd:enumeration value="string" />
                <xsd:enumeration value="long" />
                <xsd:enumeration value="boolean" />
                <xsd:enumeration value="date" />
                <xsd:enumeration value="decimal" />
                <xsd:enumeration value="money" />
                <xsd:enumeration value="quantity" />
                <xsd:enumeration value="text" />
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:schema>
```

The end goal is for me to open this file in VS without any errors, and begin to create a mapping file so I can convert CSV to XML using BizTalk. But right now I'm not even able to create a simple xsd file which is really frustrating, I am new to all this so please forgive my ignorance.

It looks like even when I get my xml to be even smaller like below, the create xsd in VS still doesn't work:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<enfinity xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.0/xcs/impex catalog.xsd http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt dt.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.0/xcs/impex" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt" major="6" minor="1" family="enfinity" branch="enterprise" build="build">
  <offer sku="423182110">
    <custom-attributes>
      <custom-attribute name="sizeEU" dt:dt="string">42</custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
  </offer>
</enfinity>
```

Comment: XSDs which are generated from examples are not reliable. You understand the structure of the data, so I strongly recommend that you _design_ the XSD yourself. Then you will understand why it works, and how to modify it.

Comment: I've updated my question at the end by pasting in an even simpler xml file, how would you recommend to create an xsd based on just that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correctly generated two schema documents, one for each of the two namespaces used in your source XML, and it's correctly generated an `xs:import` that references one of them from the other. But in the `xs:import`, it hasn't actually generated a schemaLocation attribute, presumably because it doesn't know where you are going to put the two schema documents. You need to add the `schemaLocation` by hand.

Note, I disagree with @kimbert, I think that using a schema generator is a perfectly good way of generating a starter schema for your data. But it will never be perfect: you will always need to modify it by hand to reflect what you know about the semantics of the data. For example, it has chosen `xs:unsignedInt` as the data type for a SKU, but that choice would be wrong if leading zeroes are significant and need to be retained.

Comment: Again please excuse my complete ignorance but which file do I need to add schemaLocation to?  I can see in the xml it already has that line but that's not the file giving me the issue, it's the larger of the 2 xsd so I'm assuming that's the file I need to modify in order to open it in VS?  But if that's the case what do I need to add and which line if the smaller of the 2 xsd files is currently sitting in C:\Users\TommyTam\Downloads\Upload To Exponea\Mulesoft\Item Variant Flow Poll\Item Variant Flow Poll_XML (ADDITIONAL).xsd
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add it to the xs:import. However, I'm seriously concerned that you shouldn't be creating or modifying XSD files without having a basic knowledge of the language. Generating XSD's is a great help to getting started but you need to know enough about XSD to understand what's been generated and know where to make changes.

Comment: I learn best on the job, I have actually created 1 xsd before as well as mapping files in BizTalk to convert a csv to xml, it's just in this example I have never come across dt:dt before.
In the larger xsd file, I changed <xs:import namespace="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt" /> to <xs:import namespace="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt"  dt:schemaLocation="C:\Users\TommyTam\Downloads\Upload To Exponea\Mulesoft\Item Variant Flow Poll\Item Variant Flow Poll_XML (ADDITIONAL).xsd dt.xsd"/> which is the smaller xsd but the same error persists.